# how to iterate over a list of maps in clojure and concatenate that to a string

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a list of maps with two keys :path and :size

```
 listOfMaps ({:path "a " :size "1 "}{{:path "b " :size " 2"}...)
```

how to iterate over it and concatenate its path and size to a string so that it is in between

that is

```
 str "initial" "a" "1" "b" "2" .... "end"
```

ie path and size populated through loop should be between strings "initial" and "end"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(apply str
       `("initial"
         ~@(mapcat (juxt :path :size) list-of-maps)
         "end"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's heavy but I found it funny

```
(defn str-values [data]
  (as-> data d
        (map vec d)
        (flatten d)
        (remove keyword? d)
        (concat ["initial"] d ["end"])
        (apply str d)))
```

Outputs

```
"initiala1b2end"
```

Is that what you want ?

**EDIT**
Correction by OlegTheCat

```
(defn str-values [data]
  (as-> data d
        (map (juxt :path :size) d)
        (flatten d)
        (remove keyword? d)
        (concat ["initial"] d ["end"])
        (apply str d)))
```

Comment: `(map vec d)` - this is incorrect. you cannot rely on order of map keys.

Comment: Instead I'd suppose to use `(map (juxt :path :size) d)`.